# Locust.io sequential task set not running sequentially

Tags: python, locust

I am total newbie to Python. I am writing my first Python class this week to run Locust.io load test on our API.
I have setup the code below.

```
import random
from locust import HttpUser, SequentialTaskSet, task, between
from datetime import datetime

class CredentialLoadTest(SequentialTaskSet):

    @task
    def post_credential(self):
        print("==========================")
        print("========== POST ==========")
        print("==========================")
        print("==========POST END===========")


    @task
    def get_credential(self):
        print("==========================")
        print("========== GET ===========")
        print("==========================")
        print("==========GET END===========")

    @task
    def put_credential(self):
        print("==========================")
        print("========== PUT ===========")
        print("==========================")
        print("==========PUT END===========")


class AwesomeUser(HttpUser):
    tasks = [CredentialLoadTest]
    host = "https://url.com"

    # wait time between tasks, 5 and 9 seconds
    wait_time = between(5, 9)
```

I have removed all of the actual testing code for my API endpoints here. I just simply wanted to validate if the tasks are running sequentially. When I run this code I get the output shown below.

```
[2020-07-29 21:14:54,067] 8a7f07ddbe29/INFO/locust.main: Starting web
interface at http://:8089 [2020-07-29 21:14:54,077]
8a7f07ddbe29/INFO/locust.main: Starting Locust 1.1 [2020-07-29
21:15:01,123] 8a7f07ddbe29/INFO/locust.runners: Hatching and swarming
2 users at the rate 2 users/s (0 users already running)...
==========================
========== GET ===========
==========================
==========GET END=========== [2020-07-29 21:15:01,624] 8a7f07ddbe29/INFO/locust.runners: All users hatched: AwesomeUser: 2 (0
already running)
==========================
========== GET ===========
==========================
==========GET END===========
==========================
========== POST ==========
==========================
==========POST END===========
==========================
========== POST ==========
==========================
==========POST END===========
==========================
========== PUT ===========
==========================
==========PUT END===========
==========================
========== PUT ===========
==========================
==========PUT END===========
==========================
========== GET ===========
==========================
==========GET END===========
==========================
========== GET ===========
==========================
==========GET END===========
```

As you can see the order of tasks running is **`GET`, `POST PUT`**. The order **I want is `POST`, `GET` and `PUT`**.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE Python is v3.8.5

Comment: OK, so attribute order should be preserved, see [PEP520](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0520/)

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Using your test plan (and python 3.7.7, locust 1.1.1), I get the correct order. No idea what could be causing the problem for you though... Maybe try updating locust? I dont remember any changes in this area though...

Comment: One additional note, not that it should make a difference, but I am running locust using the docker image provided by locust. I'm running locust and my python code in that docker container.

Answer (score 3):

So I still could not get the sequential task set to work properly. So I kind of "hacked" a solution that is working for me. I basically created one task as my starting point and then it calls my other "tasks" which are just normal Python functions.
This is working perfectly for me, its running each of my API operations in the order I originally wanted.

```
# GET newly created credential


def get_credential(self):
    print_log("<========== GET ===========>")
    print_log("<========== GET END ========>", True)

# PUT newly created credential


def put_credential(self):
    print_log("<========== PUT ===========>")
    print_log("<======== PUT END ========>", True)


# DELETE newly created credential

def delete_credential(self):
    print_log("<========= DELETE =========>")
    print_log("<======= DELETE END =======>", True)


class CredentialLoadTestPost(TaskSet):
    print_log("*** LOCUST API LOAD TEST Started ***", True)

    # Create new credentail
    @task
    def post_credential(self):
        print_log("<========== POST ==========>")
        print_log("<========= POST END========>", True)
        get_credential(self)
        put_credential(self)
        delete_credential(self)


class AwesomeUser(HttpUser):
    tasks = {CredentialLoadTestPost}

    # wait time between tasks, 5 and 9 seconds assume someone who is browsing the Locust docs,
    wait_time = between(5, 9)
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have executed locust with more than one user
`2 users at the rate 2 users/s`
So I assume that we see in your output prints from two parallel users.
It works in this way because task sequences are running in different threads.

Comment: To further improve your answer, you might want to explain what *running in different threads* exactly means. Also, you might want to point out recommended solutions to the problem.